# How do I write a proper graphQL query to retrieve/filter 'tags' from ghost CMS in gatsby?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, ghost-blog

My goal is to filter posts in Gatsby from Ghost CMS using the GraphQL query with a "haka" tag.

The sample provided [gatsbyghost](https://github.com/TryGhost/gatsby-source-ghost) is:

```
{
  allGhostPost(filter: {tags: {elemMatch: {slug: {eq: $slug}}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        slug
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I applied my query to file `gatsby-node.js` as follows:

```
const path = require(`path`)
const config = require(`./src/utils/siteConfig`)
const { paginate } = require(`gatsby-awesome-pagination`)

/**
* Here is the place where Gatsby creates the URLs for all the
* posts, tags, pages and authors that we fetched from the Ghost site.
*/
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions

    /**
    * Posts
    */
    const createPosts = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const postTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/post.js`)
        const indexTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/index.js`)
        resolve(
            graphql(`
                {
                    allGhostPost(filter: {tags: {elemMatch: {slug: {eq: "haka"}}}}) (
                        sort: {order: ASC, fields: published_at}
                    ) {
                        edges {
                            node {
                                slug
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }`
            ).then((result) => {
                if (result.errors) {
                    return reject(result.errors)
                }
```

It comes out with error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `PageRenderer`.

Did I put the code in the wrong place?  Or have I formatted incorrectly? Or do I need to update other files for the query to run?

Comment: It looks like your error message doesn't have anything to do with your graphql query (it's saying you're passing in `undefined` where it should have been a string or a React component). Can you share your template file?

Comment: Also, the `resolve()` that's wrapping `graphql` makes the inside `reject(result.error)` useless -- if you're resolving something inside the first resolve, it'll be useless as well. You should remove the wrapping `resolve()`

Comment: Thanks Derek!  Ok, please find attached a link to the file I have edited: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nkp6v2yc3c75o2/gatsby-node.js?dl=0

The original file that came with the gatsby ghost install is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wss9d6uxpzkzmxu/gatsby-node%20original.js?dl=0

The change on `line 21` is the only change made.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh when I commented earlier I missed the syntax error in the graphql query. Would you try correcting it to see if that's the cause of the issue?

```
  {
    // remove this line
-   allGhostPost(filter: {tags: {elemMatch: {slug: {eq: "haka"}}}}) (

    // add this 2 lines instead
+   allGhostPost(
+     filter: {tags: {elemMatch: {slug: {eq: "haka"}}}},
      sort: {order: ASC, fields: published_at}
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

When passing in multiple arguments, you can separate them with the comma:

```
query {
  allGhostPost(filter: ... , sort: ....) { ... }
}
```

---

Also, now that I see the full code, you should definitely remove the outer `resolve`:

```
const createPosts = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const postTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/post.js`)
    const indexTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/index.js`)
-   resolve(   
       ...
-   )
})
```

Not only it's unnecessary, it's also probably hiding the syntax error that graphql throw, which lead to your misleading error message.

Comment:  Thank you.  Fixed the crash. My posts are still not filtering, so I need to do some more diggging around...